# Reverse image searching

Tags: c#, image, search

Is there any ways to reverse the image search? Instead of scanning from top-left to bottom-right, start from bottom-left to top-right ?

That's how I scan the image

```
            for (int y = 0; y < matches.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < matches.GetLength(1); x++)
                {
                    double matchScore = matches[y, x, 0];
                    if (matchScore > threshold)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There is a Match");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Coords: {x},{y}");
                        return new Point(x, y);
                    }
                }
            }
            return new Point(-1, -1);
```

I just scan a screenshot and find matches on it using emgu.cv

Can I reverse the scan, starting from the bottom instead of top?

Let say, there is 2 matches at X100, Y100 and X350, Y350

it should scan from X350 -> X100, instead of X100 -> X350 and thus return X350, Y350

Comment: Are you asking how to run through a loop in reverse? Or how to twist the inices to mimick that? (Hint: both are trivial)

Comment: type `forr` , `tab` and visual studio will insert an inverse for loop.

Comment: Just invert you for. But what are you trying to do?

Comment: @LegacyCode if i invert the FOR loops, it won't detect anything anymore

Comment: @TaW Basically I need to start the search from the bottom X, Y instead of the top X, Y. So, if there is 4 match, X1, X2, X3, X4 it should only get X4 but it should not scan for the rest. so the actual order of the scan would be X4, X3, X2, X1. where the X4 is at the bottom and X1 at the top

Comment: _if i invert the FOR loops, it won't detect anything anymore_ But it should!

Comment: @TaW I don't know, I just tried inverting both for loops, used the same images as before and found 0 matches, if I instead use the normal loops, it gets a match

Comment: Well, then you know what to expect and can use the debugger to find out what goes wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write:

```
for ( int y = matches.GetLength(0) - 1; y >= 0; y-- )
  for ( int x = matches.GetLength(1) - 1; x >= 0; x-- )
    if ( matches[y, x, 0] > threshold )
    {
      Console.WriteLine("There is a Match");
      Console.WriteLine($"Coords: {x},{y}");
      return new Point(x, y);
    }
```

Because you return the first searched element found, it is possible that this loop and yours do not find the same result, if for example your finds a first element at the top, and this one at the bottom, so your returns the top element and this one returns the bottom element...

Choosing a loop direction depends of what you want to return first, from top to bottom or bottom to top, and from left to right or right to left.